# Odd PL1/PL2 (Long/Short Duration Power Limit) on an ASUS ROG Strix B760-I + Intel i5-12400

Tags: cpu, motherboard, intel-core-i5, turbo-boost, intel

The Long Duration Power Limit is at 205 W for an Intel i5-12400. XMP I is enabled.

How come this is possible? The PL1 (PBP, short for *Processor Base Power*) for this CPU should be 65 W according to the [official specifications](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/134586/intel-core-i512400-processor-18m-cache-up-to-4-40-ghz/specifications.html).

[image: BIOS power limits screenshot]
[image: BIOS model/version screenshot]
[image: XMP DRAM timing/voltage screenshot]

Comment: Why do you think it shouldn’t be set? What is DPTF exactly?

Comment: I am not sure what DPTF is. I think that, because the specification says the CPU will not draw more than 65 W in a long duration term so I don't understand why the motherboard is granting so much more.